# Retrieve DotA 2 inventory with ingame order

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I'm working at service using Steam Web API.
Now I use *http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/STEAMID/inventory/json/570/2* to get user items.
But this method doesn't support item order.
How can I get items like http://dota2lounge.com does?

Answer (score 6):

The URL you posted is not part of the Web API. You want to use [GetPlayerItems](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetPlayerItems).

Your call will look like this: `http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=<YOURAPIKEY>&steamid=<STEAMID>`

You will get a result like this

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": 1,
        "num_backpack_slots": 120,
        "items": [
             {
            "id": 692517120,
            "original_id": 692517120,
            "defindex": 5039,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 4,
            "inventory": 2147483976,
            "quantity": 1,
            "flag_cannot_trade": true,
            "flag_cannot_craft": true,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 153,
                    "value": 1065353216,
                    "float_value": 1
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 415,
                    "value": 1,
                    "float_value": 1.4012984643248171e-045
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "id": 947483208,
            "original_id": 947483208,
            "defindex": 4700,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 4,
            "inventory": 2147484031,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        ]

    }
}
```

The `result['items']` is an array of dictionaries in order. You will need to iterate through those to get further data